# EXE call from Node JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to call an exe from Node JS.
This takes file as an input and return csv as an output. I am using

```
 var opt = function(){
                execFile('C:\\Projects\\835\\H835ExcelCmd.exe', ['/Input = "C:\\Projects\\835\\PENQUIS_835Copy.edi"', '/output = "C:\\Projects\\835\\PENQUIS_835Copy.csv"', '/overwrite = yes','/Log = "C:\\Projects\\835\\Log_Folder"'], function(err, data) {  
                  console.log(err)
                  console.log(data.toString());                       
              });  
          }
          opt();
```

*And error is coming as
error block
Error: Command failed: C:\Projects\835\H835ExcelCmd.exe /Input = "C:\Projects\835\PENQUIS_835Copy.edi" /output = "C:\Projects\835\PENQUIS_835Copy.csv" /overwrite = yes /Log = "C:\Projects\835\Log_Folder"*

Comment: Can you try executing that exact command in the windows command line does it work there? I don't know what `H835ExcelCmd` is, but typically you pass options with values on the commandline either as `"/Log=C:\\..."` (ie no space around the `=`) or `/Log "c:\\..."` (ie no `=` between parameter name and value). Don't know, which format your command expects, but `/Log = "..."` looks weird ...

Comment: Use `["/Input", "C:\\.."]` etc. Where there would be a space in the command line you need a separate string.

Answer (score 0):

The exe is exiting with status code other than 0 for some reason.

I can't find any info on H835ExcelCmd. You'll have to find some information on it, and in what conditions it returns status codes other than 0.

Within the context of node, you can check the code by checking the status code of the child process at the callback, like so:

```js
 var opt = function(){
                const subprocess = execFile('C:\\Projects\\835\\H835ExcelCmd.exe', ['/Input = "C:\\Projects\\835\\PENQUIS_835Copy.edi"', '/output = "C:\\Projects\\835\\PENQUIS_835Copy.csv"', '/overwrite = yes','/Log = "C:\\Projects\\835\\Log_Folder"'], function(err, data) {
                  console.log(subprocess.exitCode);  
                  console.log(err)
                  console.log(data.toString());                       
              });  
          }
          opt();
```

Depending on what the full picture is, you may ignore the error if the exit code is this particular status code, or validate your arguments so that the exe doesn't return this status code.

As already suggested, you can also try to run the full command from the command line. e.g. this should be equivalent in PowerShell

```
C:\\Projects\\835\\H835ExcelCmd.exe '/Input = "C:\\Projects\\835\\PENQUIS_835Copy.edi"' '/output = "C:\\Projects\\835\\PENQUIS_835Copy.csv"' '/overwrite = yes' '/Log = "C:\\Projects\\835\\Log_Folder"'
```

and you can get the status code of the last executed command in powershell with

```
$LASTEXITCODE
```